# Bash Script - Will not completely execute

Tags: bash, shell, grep

I am writing a script that will take in 3 outputs and then search all files within a predefined path. However, my `grep` command seems to be breaking the script with error code 123. I have been staring at it for a while and cannot really seem the error so I was hoping someone could point out my error. Here is the code:

```
#! /bin/bash -e

#Check if path exists
if [ -z $ARCHIVE ]; then
  echo "ARCHIVE NOT SET, PLEASE SET TO PROCEED."
  echo "EXITING...."
  exit 1
elif [ $# -ne 3 ]; then
  echo "Illegal number of arguments"
  echo "Please enter the date in yyyy mm dd"
  echo "EXITING..."
  exit 1
fi

filename=output.txt

#Simple signal handler 
signal_handler()
{
  echo ""
  echo "Process killed or interrupted"
  echo "Cleaning up files..."
  rm -f out
  echo "Finsihed"
  exit 1
}

trap 'signal_handler' KILL
trap 'signal_handler' TERM
trap 'signal_handler' INT

echo "line 32"
echo $1 $2 $3

#Search for the TimeStamp field and replace the / and : characters
find $ARCHIVE | xargs grep -l "TimeStamp: $2/$3/$1"

echo "line 35"
fileSize=`wc -c out.txt | cut -f 1 -d ' '`

echo $fileSize

if [ $fileSize -ge 1 ]; then
   echo "no"
   xargs -n1 basename < $filename
else
   echo "NO FILES EXIST"
fi
```

I added the echo's to know where it was breaking. My program prints out line 32 and the args but never line 35. When I check the exit code I get 123.

Thanks!

Notes:

ARCHIVE is set to a test directory, i.e. `/home/'uname'/testDir`

$1 $2 $3 == yyyy mm dd (ie a date)

In testDir there are N number of directories. Inside these directories there are data files that have contain data as well as a time tag. The time tag is of the following format: `TimeStamp: 02/02/2004 at 20:38:01`

The scripts goal is to find all files that have the date tag you are searching for.

Comment: Why not just use `xargs grep -l "TimeStamp: $2/$1/$3"`? Variables are automatically substituted in double quotes. I'm not even sure your use of the quotes is legal in this case.

Comment: Can you post a self-contained example that we can run? The main issues are: what is `$ARCHIVE`, and what are the values of `$1`, `$2`, and `$3`?

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: Updated to answer your questions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a simpler test case that demonstrates your problem:

```
#!/bin/bash -e
echo "This prints"
true | xargs false
echo "This does not"
```

The snippet exits with code 123.

The problem is that `xargs` exits with code `123` if any command fails. When xargs exits with non-zero status, `-e` causes the script to exit.

The quickest fix is to use `|| true` to effectively ignore `xargs`' status:

```
#!/bin/bash -e
echo "This prints"
true | xargs false    || true
echo "This now prints too"
```

The better fix is to not rely on `-e`, since this option is misleading and unpredictable.

Comment: Yep, the -e was messing me up... Removed it and everything is working as expected. Thank you!!

Comment: Didn't see your answer. However I have some points too so I'd keep mine :) +1

Answer (score 1):

`xargs` makes the error code `123` when `grep` returns a nonzero code even just once. Since you're using `-e` (`#!/bin/bash -e`), `bash` would exit the script when one of its commands return a nonzero exit code. Not using `-e` would allow your code to continue. Just disabling it on that part can be a solution too:

```
set +e  ## Disable
find "$ARCHIVE" | xargs grep -l "TimeStamp: $2/$1/$3"  ## If one of the files doesn't match the pattern, `grep` would return a nonzero code.
set -e  ## Enable again.
```

Consider placing your variables around quotes to prevent word splitting as well like `"$ARCHIVE"`.

`-d '\n'` may also be required if one of your files' filename contain spaces.

```
find "$ARCHIVE" | xargs -d '\n' grep -l "TimeStamp: $2/$1/$3"
```